# Arbitrary union of measure $0$ open sets has measure $0$ in a separable metric space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, borel-measures, second-countable

Let $X$ be a separable metric space, with $(X, \tau)$ the corresponding topological space, and let $\mu$ be a (positive) measure on $(X, \mathcal{B}(X))$, where $\mathcal{B}(X)$ is the Borel $\sigma-$algebra generated by the metric topology. I am trying to prove the following result.

Let $\mathcal{U} := \{ U \mathrm{~is~open}: \mu(U) = 0 \}.$ Then $\mu \left (\bigcup \limits_{U \in \mathcal{U}} U \right) = 0.$

Attempt:

Because $X$ is second-countable, there exist countably many open sets $U_1, U_2, \ldots$ such that $\bigcup \limits_{U \in \mathcal{U}} U = \bigcup \limits_{n = 1}^\infty U_n.$ It follows that $\mu \left (\bigcup \limits_{U \in \mathcal{U}} U \right ) \leq \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \mu(U_n).$

My question is the following: How do we know that $\mu(U_n) = 0$ for all $n$?

This fact is used without explanation in the textbook "Probability measures on metric spaces" by K.R. Parthasarathy, Chapter 2, in the proof of Theorem 2.1. You can assume that $\mu$ is a probability measure, although I don't see why this would help.

Comment: This is not true and I don't see this in Theroem 2.1 in my copy of the book. Perhaps you are missing some hypothesis on $\mu$ (like regularity).

Comment: In $X=\mathbb R$, each 1 point subset $\{x\}$ has Lebesgue measure zero. So if the statement you are trying to prove were *true* it would follow that $\mathbb R = \bigcup_{x \in \mathbb R} \{x\}$ has measure zero, which of course is false.

Comment: @bof Thank you, I have modified the question.

Comment: @geetha290krm The theorem is Theorem 2.1 in Chapter 2, under the section "Spectrum of a Measure." The statement of my question is used in the proof of this theorem. The theorem claims that any probability measure on a metric space $X$ is regular.

Comment: @LeeMosher $\{x\}$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology. It is open in the discrete topology, but the corresponding Borel $\sigma-$algebra contains sets that we can't measure with Lebesgue.

Comment: I misread the fine print. Symbols for the topology itself are often avoided; instead of writing $U \in \tau$ one would write "$U$ is open".

Comment: @LeeMosher Thanks, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research, I found the following:

A separable metric space is a Lindelöf space, that is, a topological space in which every open cover has a countable subcover.

Trivially, $\mathcal{U}$ is an open cover of $\bigcup \limits_{U \in \mathcal{U}} U$. Because $X$ is Lindelöf, it has a countable subcover $\{U_n\}_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ such that $U_n$ is open and $\mu(U_n) = 0$ for all $n$. It follows that $\mu \left (\bigcup \limits_{U \in \mathcal{U}} U \right ) \leq \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \mu(U_n) = 0.$

Comment: Did you add separability after I posted my comnment?

Comment: @geetha290krm Yes, as a consequence of bof's comment. But Theorem 1.2 of Chapter 2 of the cited book, which implies that every measure on a metric space is regular, does not require separability.